# ModelValidatorProviders based on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've created custom ModelValidatorProvider which should be active only in some specific actions in the site.
In order to do that, I've created a custom attribute which extends the "FilterAttribute" and inside the OnAuthorize I'm setting the validator.

Inside the filter attribute - in order to set the validator only in the required pages, I'm doing this (PostAttributeModelValidatorProvider is the validator provider).

```
        var provider = (from p in ModelValidatorProviders.Providers
                        where p is PostAttributeModelValidatorProvider
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (provider != null)
        {
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(provider);
        }

        if (EnableAttributesValidation)
        {
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new PostAttributeModelValidatorProvider() { BypassRequiredFieldsValidation = this.BypassRequiredFieldsValidation });
        }
```

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes (I couldn't detect exactly when it goes wrong - but I believes that it occurs when two uses tries to access the site or the pages that triggers this action) there is a conflict between the remove and addition operations that I'm doing and because of that - I'm getting an error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The relevant stack trace is:

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>   System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext() +112
>   System.Linq.d_*71`1.MoveNext() +643
>
>   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +578
>
>   System.Linq.d*_14`2.MoveNext() +578
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.GetValidationAttributes(IEnumerable`1
>   clientRules, IDictionary`2 results) +440
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String
>   name, ModelMetadata metadata) +280
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object
>   value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean
>   isExplicitValue, String format, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +1050
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1
>   htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String format, IDictionary`2
>   htmlAttributes) +202    ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\interpub\wwwroot\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:47

The complete source code for the attribute is:

```
public class InitializePostAttributesResolverAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public InitializePostAttributesResolverAttribute()
        : this(true, false)
    {

    }

    public InitializePostAttributesResolverAttribute(bool enableAttributesValidation, bool bypassRequiredFieldsValidation)
    {
        this.EnableAttributesValidation = enableAttributesValidation;
        this.BypassRequiredFieldsValidation = bypassRequiredFieldsValidation;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Should the attributes input be validated
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableAttributesValidation { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value whether we should bypass the required fields validation
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This value should be set to true only if you would like to skip on required fields validation.
    /// We should use this value when searching.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool BypassRequiredFieldsValidation { get; set; }

    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new PostAttributeModelMetadataProvider();

        var provider = (from p in ModelValidatorProviders.Providers
                        where p is PostAttributeModelValidatorProvider
                        select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (provider != null)
        {
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(provider);
        }

        if (EnableAttributesValidation)
        {
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new PostAttributeModelValidatorProvider() { BypassRequiredFieldsValidation = this.BypassRequiredFieldsValidation });
        }
    }
}
```

And sample usage for it

```
    //
    // POST: /Post/Publish/5

    [InitializePostAttributesResolver]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Publish(PublishViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Am I do it right? My goal (just to be clear) is to enable the validator provider only in the decorated actions while in the other actions it should'nt be exists in the validators providers collection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelValidatorProviders.Providers` is a static property, so you cannot achieve thread-safety this way.

Instead, you should add your custom ModelValidatorProvider to the list on startup, but make provider dependent on specific attributes on the model or it's properties (same logic as DataAnnotation attributes).

```
[MyCustomValidation]
public class MyModel
{
     public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And this should do the trick.

Comment: Didn't thought on that, thanks! (Though I still need to figure out a way to add the "BypassRequiredFieldsValidation" property which should be false in search and true in add/edit - but I'll think about a way).

Comment: If you search only, you will probably populate models from database based on search word, so no validation will be triggered. Validation is triggered only when you use (Default)ModelBinder (post request, or Controller methods UpdateModel(..) and TryUpdateModel(...))

Comment: Yes I know - I got custom attributes that are been created by the DB (loose scheme with "FieldType" etc.). The validator provider validates the attributes (required, date, etc.). In search - I still need to perform validation (e.g. "Date not bigger than X" or "0 or more") but not wish to require the values - since unlike when adding or editing a record - in search they should stay optional and in this case I'm not including them in the search.